# C++ filling a char array in a loop with user-input: what exactly is happening when a whole string is entered?

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning C++ and I guess I missed something fundamental. I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is happening here:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int length = 0;
  std::cin >> length;
  char p[length];

  int i = 0;
  while(i < length){
    std::cin >> p[i];
    std::cout << ++i;
  }
  std::cout << p;
}
```

if I enter `5` as char-array length and then a whole string `abcdef` I will get `12345abcde`.

I'm wondering why a string is acceptable input in the first place and why it still runs through the rest of the loop and increments `i` every time.
I would've assumed the string is saved into the array (why is it okay that the string is longer than the array and no errors arise?) and then more input is expected - which would then be ignored (?) since the array is full. Or I would have expected an OOB like in Java.

Comment: `char p[length];` is not legal `c++`

Comment: ***I missed something fundamental.*** Use `std::string` for strings.

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions made here. For example, I'm not sure where you heard that C++ raises out-of-bounds exceptions for array accesses like Java does.

Comment: _" (why is it okay that the string is longer than the array and no errors arise?) "_ Because undefined behavior is undefined behavior and not necessarily detected at compile time or runtime.

Comment: C++ does not perform bounds checking on arrays, sometimes it could work and others it won't. "Undefined Behavior".

Comment: "I'm wondering why a string is acceptable input in the first place"   ASCII characters can be represented as `char` and as `int` that is why you can enter a "string" of char's

Comment: There's no undefined behaviour (if we accept that `char p[length];` is OK) when reading in the string; it's `std::cout << p;` that is problematic as there is no nul-terminator on the array.

Comment: A properly written program does not overrun arrays. Therefore any built-in testing of arrays accesses to ensure the program does not overrun the array is a penalty unnecessarily paid by valid programs. C++ frowns on making folks pay for stuff they didn't ask for.

Comment: In RAD Studio XE8 your code will not compile because you can not have a variable length array defined unless it is on the heap. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Microsoft compiler lacks the ability to define array length at runtime on the stack<length must be calculated at or before compile time and marked `const`>. 
Clang and gcc have both had this ability for about 15 years. It was very briefly added to the standard then removed, I believe it was C++14.

Answer (score 2):

What `cin >> p[i]` is doing is looking for characters on the command line.  This call blocks until it finds a character. When a character is found, the loop iterates, accepting a character into `p[i]`.

Since your loop only iterates the array `p` for `length`, you will never overstep the boundaries of the array. If you input more characters than specified in `length`, those characters are simply left in the input buffer.

A better solution would be to use `std::string` over a `char` array.

Comment: "are left in the input buffer" would be better than "are simply disregarded", perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You've missed quite a few fundamentals:

> ```
> std::cin >> length;
> char p[length];
> ```

The size of an array must be known at compile time (the length must be a compile time constant expression). The shown code is ill-formed in C++.

> I'm wondering why a string is acceptable input in the first place

Standard input is a character stream. A string is quite natural input for it.

> and why it still runs through the rest of the loop and increments i every time.

The loop is repeated until the condition is true. There is no condition on the increment, so that is repeated in every iteration. Eventually `i`  will reach the end condition.

> I would've assumed the string is saved into the array

At least some of it is.

> why is it okay that the string is longer than the array ...?

It's not OK. I see no reason to assume that it is.

> and no errors arise

The language was not specified to raise an error when an array is accessed out of bounds. Instead...

> which would then be ignored (?) since the array is full.

The behaviour is undefined.

> Or I would have expected an OOB like in Java.

I recommend not to make assumptions based on other languages.

Answer (score 1):

*"I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is happening here:"*

I have added comments to your code to address the question above.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int length = 0;             // declare an integer variable length and set it to 0
  std::cin >> length;         // get input from user and store it in variable length
  char p[length];             // declare a character array named p to the size of "length"
                              // this is not legal in standard c++. It is an extension 
                              // that some compilers support as pointed out by (drescherjm)
  int i = 0;                  // declare an integer variable i and set it to 0
  while(i < length){          // loop block while i is less then the value of length
    std::cin >> p[i];         // get input from user and store that value in element i of the p array

    std::cout << ++i;         // increment the value of i and output the value to the console
  }
  std::cout << p;             // output the the contents of the p array to the console.
}
```